# Compile a single CS project in a solution twice, one with a preprocessor constant defined and one without it

Tags: c#, compilation, msbuild, console, c-preprocessor

The idea is mainly to make my service read-only (due to security reasons) by checking whether a preprocessor constant is defined or not. I will have

```
#if READONLY
        throw new NotImplementedException();
#elseif
        //code implementation here
#endif
```

in my implementation. I can pass or define the constant READONLY through msbuild parameters when I compile the solution.

Now coming to the point, the issue I face is, I want the particular service implementation project to be compiled twice in a single compilation cycle, one with the constant defined and one without it.

Welcome any help.

Comment: Just add a new configuration to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a second project and add the files *as link*.